# Stripping libc.so.6 of FS register

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction, glibc, libc

I'd like to compile glibc and get rid the binary of the register FS (used for indexing).
I'm compiling using the following:
make CFLAGS='-O1 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fno-stack-protector -mno-tls-direct-seg-refs'
But the resulting binary still uses the register FS.

Comment: Did you try picking a CPU that doesn't *have* a FS?

Comment: That is a good suggestion actually. Unfortunately I have to compile it  on a 64bit machine, and as far as I know, those registers (FS/GS) are present.

Comment: And why can't you use `-mcpu` and/or `-march`?

Comment: yes I could, but it has to be compiled for 64bit machines (it has to use the 64 bit registers)

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to compile glibc and get rid the binary of the register FS

Whatever for?

You can't target `x86_64` and make GLIBC *not* use `%FS` register -- since *all* x86_64 machines have it, such a configuration is simply never implemented.

Well, in theory you could *port* GLIBC to such a pretend-it-exists machine architecture, but that is *a lot* of work.

Comment: Long story short: I have a framework that I have to use that does not handle the FS register. The problem is that in order to do what you suggest, I would need a 64 bit machine which doesn't have the FS register, but as you said it's impossible.